# Не запускается виртуальное окружение django!

Tags: python-3.x, django, manjaro

Доброе утро.
У меня linux manjaro.
Был джанго проект который был установлен в виртуальное окружение.

Сегодня Тренировался в скриптах python
и в командной строкe установил pyperclip.
Без su он не установился то есть я ввел:

```
$su

$pip install pyperclip
```

В скриптах он не заработал,но это пол беды
Когда я вошел в проект джанго и запустил как обычно виртуальное окружение и runserver то вывелось сообщение:Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

удаление пакета pyperclip  не помогло.
Ладно, думаю не впервой переписывать проекты,потренируюсь!
Создал новую папку,виртуальное окружение, джанго проект и запустил сервер!
Все заработало!
Захожу в браузер иду на локальный сервер и вместо привычной ракеты вижу перенаправление http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/ который был в моем проекте который перестал запускаться.
Прошу помощи!

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился запуском сервера на другом порту.
Вопрос как отвязать 8000 порт от старого проекта?что бы редирект не направлял на

> 127.0.0.1.8000/catalog/

а заходил на

> 127.0.0.1.8000

Comment: Кэш в браузере почистить

Comment: После перезапуска компьютера порт должен освободиться. Не знаю как это быстрее сделать) У вас старый процесс остался на этом порту